# Need help to understand a step to simplify this boolean expression

Tags: boolean-algebra

Looking my professor steps to simplify a boolean expression, he went from

$$A'(B+C)(A+B)C'+B'$$

to

$$A'(B+C)BC'+B'.$$

I've been trying to understand how did he do that but I can't.
Can anyone help me clarify how this step was done?

Comment: What does the slash mean?

Comment: Negation, sorry but it's simillar to A'

Comment: Then just use distributivity, and the fact that $A'A=0$, where $A'$ is the negation of $A$.

Comment: Ouch, true, omg ty

Comment: I've upvoted your question as a courtesy for being your first one. Next time, consider to type it with MathJax.

Comment: Certainly Amrsa, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Simply by using distributivity. Indeed
$$
A'(B+C)(A+B)C'= A'(B+C)AC' + A'(B+C)BC'
$$
But now $A'A= 0$, so you can now easily conclude.